# Parse string to decimal, commas and periods

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

How to parse string to decimal so it would work for both formats - w/ commas and periods?

```
[Fact]
public void foo(){
  var a="1,1";
  var b="1.1";
  Assert.Equal(Parse(a),Parse(b));
}
private decimal Parse(string s){
  return decimal.Parse(s,NumberStyles.Any,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

output:

```
Test 'Unit.Sandbox.foo' failed: Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: 11
Actual:   1,1
```

Comment: Even if it parsed, why would they be equal? One is 1 point 1, the other is eleven...? (since you are explicitly stating the invariant culture)

Comment: @Marc Gravell I'm not sure I understood You correctly. Anyway - aim is to write parse function so it would understood both formats. Assert reflects what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Arnis: I believe Mark was referring to ambiguity of supporting both decimal point and thousands separator using different cultures. But I believe you are only concerned in parsing decimal points?

Comment: @Arnis - I *understand*, but: both are valid numbers in both a ".=point" and a ",=point" culture. How do you propose to understand which is intended? In the "1,1" you could perhaps fake it, but what about "1.001" vs "1,001" ? Are they the same? Regardless of whether you use , or . as "point", one is one thousand and one, and the other is one point zero zero one.

Comment: @Marc reminds me "Humanity fail" blog post by Jon http://bit.ly/kQUJcR T_T

Comment: So the answer is - this should not be even tried... damn...

Comment: @Arnis I might not put it as strongly as that, but it would be a lot easier if the caller could pass the appropriate culture with it...

Comment: @Marc thanks. But I kind a fixed this problem from another point of view. Only problem left is what to do with this question. :)

Answer (score 10):

You could try that:

```
private decimal Parse(string s){
  s = s.Replace(",", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
  return decimal.Parse(s,NumberStyles.Any,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: If the OP wants to support thousands separator chars, then this won't work.

Comment: @Groo, indeed, but I can't see how he could support thousands separator if both comma and point should be treated the same way...

Comment: @Thomas it's not possible... :(

Comment: @Arnis L., what is not possible?

Comment: @Arnis L., it works if you decide not to handle thousands separator

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
private static decimal Parse(string s)
    {
        s = s.Replace(",", ".");
        return decimal.Parse(s);
    }
```

Comment: try it yourself: 1.000.000,25 and 1000000.25

Answer (score 1):

You should get the desired result by modifying the Currency decimal separator to a comma before a parse on a comma decimal string. There are some food resources here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimalseparator.aspx#Y888

You could alternatively implement your own Iformatprovider as discussed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx

Oh, or you could do a dirty hack and simply run a string replace on "," with "." ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an English-language operating system, this method converts a decimal number with a comma to a dot. If you have Russian, the method converts a decimal number with a dot to a comma.

```
Console.Write("Input number: ");
string? input = Console.ReadLine();
decimal number = ConvertNumberToCurrentLocale(input);
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + number);

decimal ConvertNumberToCurrentLocale(string? input)
{
    string separator = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    switch (separator)
    {
        case ".":
            input = input?.Replace(",", ".");
            break;
        case ",":
            input = input?.Replace(".", ",");
            break;
    }
    decimal.TryParse(input, out var number);
    return number;
}
```